# Enabling Application Cache in WkWebView using private API in Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, iphone-privateapi, application-cache

According to sources ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29896911/730807),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30230096/730807))

The below category that uses private API usually found in Safari lets WkWebView enable Application cache

```
@interface WKPreferences (MyPreferences)
- (void)_setOfflineApplicationCacheIsEnabled:(BOOL)offlineApplicationCacheIsEnabled;
@end
```

I wanted to implement application cache using Swift so I made the conversion of above code

```
extension WKPreferences {
    func _setOfflineApplicationCacheIsEnabled(offlineApplicationCacheIsEnabled: Bool) {
    }
}
```

But in swift its not working.

Here is the [sample](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm) url that has application cache.I tried this in safari it works perfectly but not in WkWebView

Comment: Did you manage to do it? Can you expose a sample how to use this private API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should import the ObjC version you have above into your bridging file. then in swift call the now exposed method directly.